# jQuery How can I check if a number exists in an element?

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to check if a number exists in an element, particularly in its class.  I have something like the following.

```
<div class'some awesome class 7 name'> More awesomeness </div>
```

How do pick out that 7?  Or better yet, how do I determine that there is a number present in the class name? (it may not always be 7)

I tried using indexOf with regex (see below), but it does not work.  Please advise.

```
$(this).html().indexOf(/\d/g)
```

Comment: What is `$(this)`, in context? And a class-name starting with a number-character is valid, in HTML 5, but a pain to select in css.

Comment: `this.className.indexOf('7')` <- will also match `some77` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume "this" represents the matched div, you can use the test method

```
var regex = /\d+/g;
var className = $(this).attr('class');
var numberInElement  = regex.test(className); // true or false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hLpr51ut/1/

If the number should exist at a boundary (whitespace, beginning or end) your regex would be /\b\d+\b/g